# ErrorDocument in dynamic SubFolder

Tags: htaccess, apache

I host different Websites in 1 web space. But I don't want to give the `ErrorDocument` an absolute SubFolder name.

Is it possible to make `website` a variable?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /website/error?error=404
```

Can `.htaccess` auto detect the SubFolder (including SubFolder depth)?

For example, a website written by myself where I've the same "system" twice or more e.g. productive, test and development. So all of them have different SubFolders. If someone wants to host the website by himself and use the SubFolder `root/website/test/MyWebsite`. So `.htaccess` needs to auto detect the SubFolder to redirect to the error page. So the user doesn't need to change the absolute path to `website/test/MyWebsite/error...`.

Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32)
Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 20 2015

EDIT:
This forks fine for myself

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^\.]+)/
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDIR:%1]

ErrorDocument 404 /%{reqenv:SUBDIR}/error?error=404
```

Comment: Are all these websites using the same codebase or do all have separate web roots? You could set different 404 page for each website by just using htaccess in each sites directory.

Comment: @Analog I edit my question to show clearly what i want/need.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32)  Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 20 2015

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32)

---

> Is it possible to make `website` a variable?

Not before Apache 2.4.13 unfortunately.

> Can `.htaccess` auto detect the SubFolder (including SubFolder depth)?

This depends on the module you are using in `.htaccess`, rather than `.htaccess` itself. For instance, mod_rewrite (when used in a per-directory context) works relative to the directory in which it is contained and can be used to extract the subdirectory path from the URL. `ErrorDocument` is a core directive, paths are relative to the `DocumentRoot`.

If you were on Apache 2.4.13+ then... from the [Apache docs for ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument):

> From 2.4.13, [expression syntax](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) can be used inside the directive to produce dynamic strings and URLs.

Which means you could do "something like" this:

```
# Assign the subdirectory to an environment variable
# Note the slash prefix is excluded from the captured pattern
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDIR:%1]

# Set ErrorDocument dynamically to this subdirectory
# Requires Apache 2.4.13+
# The 2nd argument to the ErrorDocument directive must be prefixed with a slash
# in the source code itself for it to be interpreted as a local path.
ErrorDocument 404 /%{reqenv:SUBDIR}/e404.php
```

## Alternative - Subdomains

An alternative, that would work on all versions of Apache, is to use subdomains instead of subdirectories. The subdomain can point to the subdirectory if you wish, but you would need to access the site through the subdomain.

The important thing with the subdomain is that the document root changes. So your `ErrorDocument` directive can be kept simple:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error?error=404
```

The path (starting with a slash) is relative to the `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I updated my Apache Version an tried your proposal but I didn't work like I (You) expected. It only append the string `expr=%{reqenv:SUBDIR}/error?error=404` to an blank page

Comment: If I use it without the quote like `{reqenv:SUBDIR}/error?error=404` it append the right Sub Folder name `/website/error?error=404` but it didn't show the page

Comment: Presumably you saw the literal text "/website/error?error=404"? Maybe it needs the slash prefix (`/`) to be present in the directive itself for it to be seen as a URL-path rather than a literal string (the "error message")? I've changed the code in my answer to reflect this. To confirm, you've found you don't need the `expr=%` prefix? Unfortunately I'm unable to test this myself at the current time. Whilst "Apache Expressions" are available from Apache 2.4+, being able to use them with the `ErrorDocument` directive is a more recent addition.

Comment: Now it forks fine with `ErrorDocument 404 /%{reqenv:SUBDIR}/error?error=404` Thanks for help

Comment: I updated your and my Code. Now it works for unlimited sub folders

Answer (score 2):

People often forget about using symlinks. You can create a symlink for each site that points to a single directory. This means that a relative URI of /error/error404.html can all point to the same directory/file even outside of the/any web root.

This answer on another SE site covers the topic enough to get started: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link

Comment: But in my case this isn't an option because some users (including myself) use windows. And the website should be usable without great effort like `symbolic link`

Comment: @DestinatioN I read Apache and assumed.... well, never mind! Symlinks are simple. There is a virtual directory option on windows. I assume that this is a one time set-up thing, however, if it is not, then I assume PHP will let you create a symlink/virtual directory. If not PERL can. It is an option. If these ideas do not work for you, that is okay. I will keep thinking about it for you. Cheers!!

Comment: thanks for the help, but I prefer w3dk's solution

Comment: @DestinatioN I don't blame you! I like it too!! w3dk is outstanding. This question is squarely within his wheel-house. He is our expert on .htaccess and regular expressions. I do these things too, but I am also completely out of practice. Oh well. That is the price of being retired. What is important is that you get the best possible answer that works for you. All else does not matter. You matter. That is why we are here. Cheers!!